# How to create a function that can return anything in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How do make a function return *, by star, I mean the function is able to return anything, and then I can typecast it accordingly?

```
private function get_current_files_view():TileList
    {
        var tlist:TileList;
        //switch(this[fm_model.files_display_type])
        switch(vs_file_display.selectedChild)
        {
            case cvs_user_files:    
                tlist = tlist_files;
                break;

            case bx_shared_data:                    
                tlist = tlist_shared_with_me;
                break;
            default:    
                throw new Error('Invalid container found');
        }
        return tlist;
    }
```

Suppose in this function, I want this function to return both tilelist and datagrid (according to the case) what should be changed.

Plz let me know
Thanks you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Suppose in this function, I want this
>   function to return both tilelist and
>   datagrid (according to the case) what
>   should be changed.

If that is the case, then you should return [ListBase](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5), which is a parent class of both the List and the DataGrid.

I you want to be able to return any object, you can specify the return type as [Object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html).

If you really want to return anything, including primitve values, such as integers you can use the *, as was stated in another answer.  IF this is truly what you need, my intuition is that you may need to refactor your application.

Comment: +1 Yes, I agree with that.  Very often (but certainly not always), * is a cop out... especially if you know you want it to be one of two types only.  I like using `ListBase`.  Returning * is great when you really CAN return anything.  If we ever get generics in AS3, then the majority of * returns will likely be generic returns instead.

Answer (score 8):

You don't NEED to define a return type.  If you don't, then you can return anything or nothing (not recommended):

```
private function get_current_files_view() { }
```

Or, you can define it that it must return something, but anything

```
private function get_current_files_view():* { }
```

Or, you could always use an interface or base class if you want to be specific:

```
private function get_current_files_view():ISomeInterface {}
```

Does this help?  Or am I completely misunderstanding your question?

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to use an interface.  I believe that is a much better development approach than having an * as the return type.

Comment: The Flex compiler in strict mode wont accept a method with no return type. It is best practice to always define a return type.

Comment: @TandemAdam: Agreed.  I like to specifically define my routines as functions (return something... *, Type, Object, etc) or procedures (returns void).  It is clear to the caller whether to expect a return or not.  I will edit my response to add that suggestion.  My variables, however, I am happy to mix in static typing and dynamic typing.  In functions, however, we should specify something.

Comment: @TandemAdam I think the claim that the Flex Compiler "won't accept a method with no return type" in strict mode is a bit inaccurate.  The Flex Compiler gives a warning, but a compile time warning doesn't prevent you from compiling the app.

Answer (score 2):

```
private function whatsMyObject:(parameter:*):*
     {
     switch  (parameter.constructor)
             {
             case TileList:     trace("parameter is TileList");
                                break;

             case DataGrid:     trace("parameter is DataGrid");
                                break;

             default:           trace("parameter is neither TileList nor DataGrid");
             }

     return parameter;
     }
```

Comment: Always better to use `is` rather than the undocumented `constructor` property. It'll catch subclasses too.

Comment: constructor is documented:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#constructor